# Quartz.Net CronTrigger scheduling not working as expected

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression, crontrigger

```cs
public static void ConfigureJob()
{
    int ScheduleTriggerDate = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduleTriggerDate"]);

    ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();


    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MailingList>().WithIdentity("job1", "group1").Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
        (s =>
            s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .OnEveryDay().StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(23, 0))
        )
        .Build();

    sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    sched.Start();
}
```

I am trying to schedule a Quartz.Net CronTrigger in a windows service. I have the above sample code and what i am trying to achieve is to schedule the job to run every day at a particular hour. On testing i am finding the above code unreliable, some times it runs and other times it just fails silently,

I have read a few posts here suggesting the use of a CronTrigger instead of the simple trigger in the my sample above.

Does any one know how i can achieve my requirement above using a CronTrigger? OR how can i improve the above sample to make it reliably run every day at a particular hour that i can set in the app.config file?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CronScheduleBuilder` to make it easy to configure `CronTrigger`:

```cs
// Extension method to round a date to a given part
var nextFire = DateTime.Now.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
           .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(nextFire.Hour, nextFire.Minute).WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
           .Build();
```

If you prefer to specify the cron expression directly (like you mentioned, from app.config file):

```cs
// Runs every day at 9am in this example.
.WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 0 9 1/1 * ? *"))
```

You can use [this site to calculate cron expressions](http://www.cronmaker.com/).